# can re-seq be made to behave like .split?

Tags: regex, clojure

Is there some regex that can be passed to re-seq such that it will behave like `.split`?

```
user=> (seq (.split "a,b,c,,e" ","))
("a" "b" "c" "" "e")
user=> (re-seq #"[^,]" "a,b,c,,e")
("a" "b" "c" "e")
user=>
```

As you can see the regex `[^,]` is not quite acceptable because it won't pick up on empty columns in a delimited file. Am I stuck with `.split` or can `re-seq` be made to work?

Comment: Why do you prefer to use re-seq when split works fine?

Comment: @MichielBorkent: Well, I ended up using `.split`. But this all started when I was doing a cascalog project, and I wanted to use cascalog's `re-parse` method to split tab delimited text (because it appeared as if it was intended to do stuff like that). And columns were getting dropped from the input and cascalog was crapping out because I told it my generator produced 7 columns and instead it was producing 5 columns for some rows. And this was because `re-parse` is implemented with `re-seq`. So ultimately I used `.split` but was just curious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
(re-seq #"[^,]+|(?<=,)(?=,)" "a,b,c,,e")
```

I hope that Clojure regexes support lookbehind assertions.

**Explanation:**

```
[^,]+       # Either match one or more non-comma characters
|           # or
(?<=,)(?=,) # match the empty string between two commas
```

Comment: actually it results in `("a" "" "b" "" "c" "" "" "e" "")` which is definitely closer but not quite.

Comment: although I would expect what you provided to work, it makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks for noticing this (RegexBuddy automatically filters out these additional empty matches, but most programming languages' regex implementations don't. This does make sense: after all, after having matched `a`, the regex engine can find zero non-commas before the next comma...). I have rewritten my regex, can you try the new one?

Comment: yes it works, but I don't think you meant to put the asterisk in the first part of the regex did you (it works both ways). Also the + is not needed either, so what I eventually got was: `(re-seq #"[^,]|(?<=,)(?=,)" "a,b,c,,e")`. Thanks!

Comment: @Kevin: Whoops. Don't know how that snuck in. I wouldn't leave out the `+`, though. At least not if elements between commas can be more than 1 character in length.